# Vilkas is acting like a guard and i cant stop him

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had a fight in White Run and Vilkas was attacking me. When I came back from jail he started acting like a guard- chasing me with weapon and starting a dialogue. I tried injuring him and it didnt work. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

This is normal

> As a follower, Vilkas has no tolerance for crime. If the Dragonborn has a bounty in any hold, Vilkas will draw his sword and advance on the Dragonborn, but will not attack unless provoked

To fix this you need to go to the White Run and pay for your crimes! As well as all the other holds you have bounties in

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vilkas

Comment: Yeah, it took me forever to get past that since I had an bounty that I wasn't allowed to pay nor go to jail for in Markath. Later though, a guard glitched and let me pay it off.

Comment: To my considerable surprise, [quite a lot of NPCs have this feature](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:GuardFaction_(makes_an_actor_a_guard)#GuardFaction_.28makes_an_actor_a_guard.29) - look at the "Members" box on the right.  Anyway, one suggested fix if you don't have any bounties is to acquire a small bounty and immediately pay it off (e.g. run up to a guard and punch them in the face).